# How to view other users profile if session is set in php

Tags: php, session

Well I am trying to create kind of a social network but there is a problem with my session. So I am not able to visit other users profile. This is my code for `loginwebsite1.php`

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '123456789', 'register');

if (isset($_POST['email1'])) {
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, htmlentities($_POST['email1']));
}

if (isset($_POST['password1'])) {
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, htmlentities($_POST['password1']));
}

if (!empty($email) && !empty($password)) {
    $query  = "select id from register where email='$email' and password='$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $row    = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if ($row > 0) {
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row;
        $_GET['id']     = $row;
        header('location: new.php');
    } else {
        echo "sorry but the email-id or password is wrong";
    }
} else {
    echo "please enter your email-id or password or there";
}
?>
```

My session code goes like this:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['id']) && !empty($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];

    foreach ($id as $fn)
        $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'id', 'password', 'register');

    $query     = "select firstname,lastname from register where id='$fn'";
    $result    = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $row       = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $firstname = $row['firstname'];
    $lastname  = $row['lastname'];
} else {
    header('location: loginwebsite1.php');
}
?>
```

But when I try to enter like `profile.php?id=9` it still opens the profile of the user who is logged in.

Comment: is that your full code? did you pass the parameter of the yoururl.php?id=9 by using $_GET['id']? your $id=$_SESSION['id'] will always return the same unless it was updated.

Comment: anyway, you mention you want to use other users profile, you shouldn't even use session to do that, session has better purpose such as authenticating a user across pages. A simple $id=$_GET['id];, with id=$id will fetch your query. But this type of syntax are prone to injections, do read up about PDO.

Answer (score 2):

```
$id=$_SESSION['id'];
```

This line is where you problem is I believe.  Here you get the ID number for the profile page to load from the $_SESSION variable when you should be getting it from the $_GET variable.

It should read:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
```

Comment: well you see i have already set $_SESSION['id'] on previous page that is loginwebsite1.php and now $_GET['id'] is not working on this page but if i set $_GET['id'] on previous page session will no longer works

Comment: The $_GET variable lets you access data that was passed in the url so $_GET['id'] corresponds to ?id= in the URL. Items stored in $_SESSION stay stored in $_SESSION between page reloads. I'm not sure if this helps at all... I had a hard time understanding what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

you should also check if the `$_GET['id']` is also set like this

```
$connection=mysqli_connect('localhost','id','password','register');
if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && !empty($_SESSION['id']) || !empty($_GET['id']))
{
    $id=!empty($_GET['id'])? $_GET['id']: $_SESSION['id'];
    foreach($id as $fn){            
        $query="select firstname,lastname from register where id='$fn'";
        $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
        $firstname=$row['firstname'];
        $lastname=$row['lastname'];
    }
}else{
    header('location: loginwebsite1.php');
}
```

also set your `$connection` variable to connect only once to your database.

Comment: The `isset($_SESSION['id'])` isn't needed, because the value isn't allowed to be empty `!empty($_SESSION['id'])` is enough.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out. but that's just a copy paste on the OP's code

Comment: well thats not working i will try to enter my loginwebsite1.php code too